# OperationNotSupportedException: Operation not supported for streaming result (ResultSet)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Given this code below:

```
if (resultSet == null) {
  pageNumber = 0;
  resultSet = getResultSet(db);
}
if (resultSet != null) {
  resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
  columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
  resultSetArray = getResultSetAsList(resultSet, columnCount);
  rowCount = resultSetArray.size();
}

countTempSize = 0;
if (rowCount > 0 && resultSetArray != null && resultSetArray.size() > 0) {
  pageNumber = pageNumber + rowCount;
  ResultSet tempResultSet = getResultSet(db);
  if (resultSet != null && tempResultSet != null) {
    if (tempResultSetArray != null && tempResultSetArray.size() > 0) {
      tempResultSetArray.clear();
    }
    tempResultSetArray = getResultSetAsList(tempResultSet, columnCount);
    for (String columnName: timestampColumnName) {
      resultSet.last();
      tempResultSet.beforeFirst();
      int i = 0;
      while (tempResultSet.next() && resultSet.getString(columnName).toString().equals(tempResultSet.getString(columnName).toString())) {
        resultSetArray.add(tempResultSetArray.get(i));
        i++;
        countTempSize++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following error occurs at `resultSet.last();`:

> ERROR Failed to run query for table
>   TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="mpdb"."meta_eligibility",
>   query='null', topicPrefix='Audit-mpdb-', incrementingColumn='',
>   timestampColumns=[created_on]}: {}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.OperationNotSupportedException: Operation not supported
>   for streaming result sets     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataCursor.notSupported(RowDataCursor.java:452)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataCursor.beforeFirst(RowDataCursor.java:260)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.first(ResultSetImpl.java:1129)   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:130)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:63)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

this is not working. How do I write it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow :) You need to provide us with more information. What does this code need to do that it is not doing right now? What IDE are you using, etc. You might want to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check the result set type and read the JDBC API documentation. Methods like `last`, `first`, etc are not supported for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result sets (and that is the case for streaming result sets).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I guess it's not the case because it's working in one environment but giving an error in another.

Comment: @jsubodh Then you should find out what the difference is (different MySQL version, different MySQL Connector/J version, etc). The behavior shown can be explained by the behavior defined by the JDBC specification for TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY result sets.